# Add Points and sort a column according to the ranking

Tags: sorting, google-sheets

I currently am working on a sheet where I have multiple categories, where each name can have different scores based on the category. Then points are given out based on their ranking and the value they got compared to the others.

In the end, I want to sum up all points for each name with ranking and value points separate and then sort the name-sum pairs based on each kind of sum total.

Here is a Link on a small version that I made based on what I am currently at, in my actual sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PGoIzBnerKfc-SpMTRqpdGQQb_6Z9Ujb6rZ6eFFivkY/edit?usp=sharing

I understand how to make the summations. (See attached sheet.) But I don't know how to sort the results.

I know it would make calculations easier if I line them up vertically. However they are easier to read horizontally, that's why I'm doing it that way.

What I want, is for the total points to be calculated, and then sorted with the corresponding names in descending order. In the example sheet, you can see the sum totals but they are not in descending order based on the total points.

Comment: Please consider provide an example for input or the desired output. It's unclear what is missing in your example sheet. An example can clarify the meaning of "then sorted with the corresponding names in descending order".

Comment: Not sure how I can clarify further, but I can try. The points in the categories should be added together. In the example of C for Ranking Points it would be 5 + 4 + 3 = 12. That would be done for all names for both ranking and value points. Then the names are ordered by those sums. That is done for Value Points as well. The sumation part is working right now. The order is currently the problem.

The picture in the other answer perfectly nails how it should look like in the end.

Comment: See my edit to your question. Please also restore the sheet. In the meantime, I can draft an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use Sumif like this

```
=sort({A3:A7,sumif(A3:A7,A3:A7,C3:C7)+sumif(F3:F7,A3:A7,H3:H7)+sumif(K3:K7,A3:A7,M3:M7)},2,0)
```

for the ranking points and

```
=sort({A3:A7,sumif(A3:A7,A3:A7,D3:D7)+sumif(F3:F7,A3:A7,I3:I7)+sumif(K3:K7,A3:A7,N3:N7)},2,0)
```

for the value points?

[image]

If you had many more than three categories, this wouldn't be practical so you would need an alternative approach - maybe flattening the data to four columns and using a query to calculate the sums and sort them. Here is a sample formula (hard-coded for the case of 5 rows of data starting in row 3, 3 sets of 4 columns with an offset of 5 columns between them)

```
=ArrayFormula(query(vlookup(mod(quotient(sequence(15,4,0),4),5)+3,{row(A3:A7),A3:N7},mod(sequence(15,4,0),4)+2+quotient(sequence(15,4,0),20)*5,false),"select Col1,sum(Col3) group by Col1 order by sum(Col3) desc label sum(Col3) ''"))
```

*Note*

If you use semicolons instead of commas, the formulas would be

```
=sort({A3:A7\sumif(A3:A7;A3:A7;C3:C7)+sumif(F3:F7;A3:A7;H3:H7)+sumif(K3:K7;A3:A7;M3:M7)};
2;0)

=sort({A3:A7\sumif(A3:A7;A3:A7;D3:D7)+sumif(F3:F7;A3:A7;I3:I7)+sumif(K3:K7;A3:A7;N3:N7)};
2;0)
```

and

```
=ArrayFormula(query(vlookup(mod(quotient(sequence(15;4;0);4);5)+3;{row(A3:A7)\A3:N7};mod(sequence(15;4;0);4)+2+quotient(sequence(15;4;0);20)*5);"select Col1,sum(Col3) group by Col1 order by sum(Col3) desc label sum(Col3) ''"))
```

Comment: The way it looks in the picture would be exactly how I want it, but when I use the formulas, the numbers are in the same column as the names. Just in the cells below them. And can therefore not sort properly. Maybe a weird region difference? I am in a region that uses semicolons instead of commas.

Comment: Will add formulas with regional settings to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For column 3 in your blocks, ie. ranking points,

```
=sort(transpose(query({A3:D7;F3:I7;K3:N7},"select sum(Col3) pivot Col1",1)),2,false)
```

For column 4 in your blocks, ie. value points,

```
=sort(transpose(query({A3:D7;F3:I7;K3:N7},"select sum(Col4) pivot Col1",1)),2,false)
```

In your locale, function inputs are separated by `;` instead of `,`. So replace the separators accordingly if Google Sheet doesn't do it automatically.

It appears that your column 4s have custom formatting. You can also apply formatting at the end but you may end up having rounding errors propagated. If you intend for the values in column 4 to be rounded, it is best to round them in the original blocks with `round()` or `roundup()`.

*Aside, unfortunately, `query()` does not inherit formatting the same way other native functions do.*

---

Let's talk about why they work and why we need to use `query()`.

For function definitions, consult [official documentation](https://support.google.com/docs#topic=1382883) and type the function name in the search bar. I'll go over their usage as applied to your example.

The sorting itself is straight forward. You use `sort()`. Suppose you have helper columns as follows:

- in P3, put either `=arrayformula(A3:A7)` or `unique({$A3:$A;$F3:$F;$K3:$K})`;
- in Q3, put `=sum(filter({C:C;H:H;M:M},{$A:$A;$F:$F;$K:$K}=$P10))`
- and spread the formula from Q3 to Q7

You can easily sort with `=sort({P3:P7,Q3:Q7},2,false)`. (*I made the ranges convenient for spread to query data for other columns. For example, to get column 4, which is Value Points, you can spread the formulas 1 column to the right. Hence the particular choices of absolute vs relative ranges.*)

In order to use `sort()`, however, as you can see in the above example, you must have a prepared range. So you need to generate the results `Q3:Q7`, which are the sum totals, at once.

The only way to do that with native functions is pivot table or query.

We don't need to dig too deeply into how `query()` works. Let us only worry about how it applies in your example.

`{}` means [local array](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en). `;` means vertical concatenation. Thus, `{A3:D7;F3:I7;K3:N7}` combines your blocks in 1 place. You should be able to drop the ending row number `7` for larger datasets.

`Col3` and `Col1` are one way you can query data columns. Since we are querying a local array, there are no letter names for the columns. Hence the use of column indices.

We want to sum column 3, Ranking Points. Hence `sum(Col3)`. `select` means we are going to output the result. `pivot Col1` means summing based on unique values of column 1 and it additionally means it will output both the unique values and what we *selected*. Moreover, the output will be a 2-by-n array where the 1st row is the unique values and 2nd row is what we selected. `sort()` only works with columns. Hence the need for `transpose()`.

It does not appear from your example that you would have very many blocks (ie. categories.) Otherwise, you can use `flatten()` and `split()` to produce the aggregated data by taking advantage of the empty columns. For example, the formula below produces the same table as `{A3:D7;F3:I7;K3:N7}` but is generalized.

```
=arrayformula(split(transpose(split(join(",",flatten(A3:O7)),",,",false)),","))
```

With that, everything is in place and we have our solution!

Comment: Thank you for the In-Depth Explaination. I will use them for reference, if further issues arise while porting the solutions over to my actual sheet. Overall the issue is now solved and the sheet behaves as intended.